# UIImagePickerController crashes on cancelling second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uiimagepickercontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` in my app and it crashes whenever I click on cancel for 2nd time and shows following crash log :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view
>   controller: should have parent
>   view controller:(null) but actual parent is:'

Dismissing code :

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The same code is working fine in other app but when I copied the code into new project the crash is occurring repeatedly.
Its happening on iOS 8.3 & 7.1, not tested on other versions.
Any help would be much appreciable.

Comment: How do you hide your `UIImagePickerController` in ...didCancel delegate method?

Comment: post the code where you are hiding the picker view.

Comment: i think you are trying to add nil object into view

Comment: @BadalShah : Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to explain ?

Comment: Please check in `imagePickerControllerDidCancel ` does picker have `parentViewController` and add please showing picker code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set delegate in `.h`

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController < UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Initialize image picker when you want to open it.

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

Delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved lot of my time. But the real issue is imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen; here I was using UIModalPresentationCurrentContext and it was causing the crash in my new app but not in previous app.